# Magento plugin same as cakephp upload plugin or some other smart method to generate thumb, small, large images

Tags: magento, cakephp, plugins

can we use upload plugin cakephp for magento to create thumb, small, large images. Or having some other extension for the same.

I want to make uploaded images in three different sizes thumb, small, large.

Is there any other extension available or someone have a smart move for the same?

Comment: Asking for extension is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Dear @Enigmativity, But asking for help to complete work faster is not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that?

Comment: Please answer the question if you know. Its not about plugin if someone is familiar to other method let me know.

Comment: It is about an extension - you explicitly asked for an extension twice in the question. And asking "someone have a smart move for the same" is also off-topic. This is a programming Q&A site where you come with a question about programming. What you have asked is not a programming question.